# I Formatted My Flash Drive to install linux..DIdnt go so well, how do i wipe the drive again, so that its back to a plain usb drive?

Tags: command-line

I used Rufus to do it as an ISO drive, Now I don't know how to revert it back to a regular USB for media files.
I tried a few web-searches, nothing came up.

Please get back to me with a solution if you know it! 
Thanks

Comment: Use a partitioning tool (whatever is bundled with your system).  If you divided the drive into multiple partitions, redo that as a single partition.  Then reformat.  See http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/ott-explains-what-file-format-is-best-for-usb-drives/ for a discussion of filesystems or https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-file-format-for-a-USB-3-0-flash-drive.  The default is typically a variant of FAT.

Answer (score 0):

Just uncheck the checkbox in front of *Create a bootable drive using...* and select the file system you want. Then press Start. That's it.

**Explanation:** Rufus can very much format a USB flash drive as a regular (non-bootable) one. You just have to tell it so by not checking the bootable option.